# Set a cookie and unknown domain - Node Js/Express

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, cross-domain

I want to set a cookie on a domain different from the Express app.

The app runs on: `http://localhost:8080`

This is the code I have:

In server.js:

```
app.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }))
```

```
const test = [1, 2, 3]

test.forEach((cookie, index) => {
    res.cookie('testCookie' + index, cookie, {
        sameSite: 'none', secure: true
    })
});

res.json({ data: 'good to go' })
```

This returns the cookies, but it does not set the cookies on the browser.

I am running this from different sites in chrome dev tools in the Console tab, for example, `yahoo.com`:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/bid', {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    redirect: 'follow',
    credentials: 'include'
})
```

In the browser, I do not receive any warnings or errors:
[image]

Comment: do you see cookies on postman?

Comment: @hazratgafulov yes, they’re there

Answer (score 0):

The attribute [`secure: true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#secure) means that the server will send the cookie only over https. But your app runs on http://localhost:8080, so it will not be sent to the browser.